# Why does the MOG provide the octads of a Steiner system

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, coding-theory, simple-groups

I have been reading about the Mathieu finite simple groups, which has taken me on an interesting detour through coding theory, and the Miracle Octad Generator (MOG). There are a lot of instructions online on *how* the MOG works, but much less on *why* it works, and it's the *why* I'd like some pointers on.

In terms of the *how*, I understand that you've got 24 points laid out onto a grid, and obeying some rules, you can extend any 5 of them to an octad of the steiner system S(5,8,24). The rules are based around parity of the rows and columns, and scoring the columns to give *hexacode words*, which are all words from a 6-dimensional codebook over the finite field $F_4$. Although a tad fiddly, this is all well and good.

In order to try and find out why it works, I have read the reference everyone gives: chapter 11 of Conway/Sloane's Sphere Packing, Lattices and Groups. But (at least it seemed to me) this source only described how to use the MOG, not why it worked. Another source that looked promising was a master's thesis by Sitt Chee Keen (http://eprints.usm.my/6567/1/ON_STEINER_SYSTEM_S%285%2C_8%2C_24%29_AND_THE_MIRACLE_OCTAD_GENERATOR_%28MOG%29.pdf) but I could only find the first half online.

Like everything Conway was interested in, it still just feels a bit magic!

Could anyone give me any intuition as to what is going on behind the scenes in the MOG to make it work? Why the hexacode? How might you prove it? Any good references? Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a proof that the MOG works, the discussion in Sphere Packing, Lattices and Groups, Chapter 11, up to section 6, shows that any octad can be uniquely completed from 5 points of the MOG. So it is a proof that the MOG gives a Steiner system.

As for the intuition behind why we would construct such a thing, well, I don't have a good answer. I have the same feeling that Conway had a way of distilling a lot of ideas to something simple and oftentimes magical-looking.

To some extent, though, I think the 5,8,24 Steiner system inherently has to be a bit magical, however it is constructed, because it is an exceptional structure. It is specific to the number 24, and doesn't generalize.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts here, I think you describe it really well. I always wonder if  there is such a thing as a "fluke" or "coincidence" in maths when exceptions crop up. If you look deep enough you can probably find some sort of reason, but sometimes you need something simple/magical just to get a handle on it first! I'm going to go and have another careful look at that Chpt 11 and see what else I can get from it....

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand deeply the "why" exactly like you, @user214962. Actually I understood it "almost" fully reading directly the article from Curtis, i.e. A new combinatorial approach to $M_{24}$. The first 3 pages dive deeply in the combinatorics about how these octads are gotten and you finally get a solid grasp about why they look like those ones. Conway's approach came later, using the Hexacode and to my view is a bit too mechanic to understand the why, but mainly helps about the how. The article you mentioned is a expansion of Curtis one helps a lot, but it's uncomplete.

Comment: @user214962, I can try eventually to explain those three pages, taking your mentioned article as a starting point, explaining also the details I've manually expanded on paper. Actually the Sitt Chee Keen's article stops abruptly exactly where the "meat" would start. It's a bit a long but could help you. Just let me know.